# afterScenario not working calling features not in the same folder

Tags: karate

afterScenario is not working if the feature that is being called is not in the same folder/package.
The feature is not being called.

For example, if the feature that the afterScenario is used is in api/users/create and has configured:
`* configure afterScenario = """function(){ karate.call('classpath:api/users/delete/delete-user.feature', { user: userId }) """`

afterScenario is not being executed. Only if the delete-user.feature is in the same folder it works.

Is there something wrong?
I've checked https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files, but not found the way to call the feature if is not in the same folder.
I've also tried to call the feature in afterScenario from a library, but not working neither.

The current version of karate is 0.9.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 karate.call('this:delete-user.feature')
```

Which will look for the file in the same folder as the imediately "calling" feature. This is explained in the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files

If you are *still* stuck, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue